# How to set class attribute of an element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is my code for generate combobox. How can I add a css class name 'chosen-select' on it ?

```
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);    
var element2 = document.createElement("select");   

var option1 = document.createElement("option");   
option1.value="";   
option1.innerHTML="--Select--";      
element2.appendChild(option1);   

var option2 = document.createElement("option");   
option2.value="1";   
option2.innerHTML="Apple";     
element2.appendChild(option2);   

element2.name = "description" + rowno;  
element2.id = "description" + rowno;   
element2.setAttribute("required","true");   
element2.style.width = "150px";   
cell3.appendChild(element2);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `className` property :

```
element2.className = "chosen-select";
```

[Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp)

Comment: thanx for your reply but its not working....

Comment: It is. You must have mistaken somewhere. Where did you put this line ?

Comment: element2.name = "description" + rowno;   
element2.id = "description" + rowno;   
element2.setAttribute("required","true");   
element2.style.width = "150px";   
element2.className = "chosen-select";   
cell3.appendChild(element2);

Comment: i am using that line on above code pls check it is right???

Comment: Works fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/wmubg/. Have you checked for javascript errors ?

Comment: Actually i am using a template css and js with my code, if you can send your mail id, i will send you that file.

Comment: No thanks. IF we do it this way, how future visitors on this topic will find the answer they need ? You should close this topic (ie. mark an answer as accepted) an open a new question with your non-working code, since this not really related to class attribute modification anymore.

Comment: Its working with normal css file properly, i drop that css code on  jsfiddle.net/wmubg. thanks to help.

Comment: I have one css file and four js file that have included on my code. how can i send my js and css file to you.

Comment: Post another question with the code and the problem. This question has already been answered.